# Почему при клике на выпадающее меню контент скролится в тор?

Tags: jquery, css

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".hide").click(function() {
            $(".dropdown").hide();
            $(this).hide();
          });
          $("menu ul li:nth-child(4)").click(function() {
            $(".dropdown").show();
            $(".hide").show();
          });
        });

        (function($) {
          $.lockfixed("menu", {
            offset: {
              top: 0,
              bottom: 650,
              opacity: .4
            }
          });
        })(jQuery);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}
.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  min-height: 1800px;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
header .header-bg,
.header-gradient,
.header-basis {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.header-bg {
  background: url(http://www.tvoishuzy.com/images/new-york-city-H.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  filter: blur(5px);
  background-color: #222;
}
.header-title {
  margin: 100px;
}
menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 0, 0, .8) 60%, rgba(255, 55, 255, .7) 100%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
}
menu ul li a {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-shadow: 0 2px rgba(1, 1, 0, 1);
  color: #fefefe;
}
menu ul li div {
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 33px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 0, 0, .8) 60%, rgba(255, 55, 255, .7) 100%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 301;
}
.dublicat {
  width: 250px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  opacity: .2;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px grey;
  transition: textshadow .3s;
}
h1.sol::selection,
h1.sol i::selection {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, .4);
}
h1.dublicat::selection,
h1.dublicat i::selection {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  background: transparent!important;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px transparent;
}
.header-gradient {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red 100%, green 10%, blue 60%);
  opacity: .2;
}
.hide {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: transparent;
  display: ;
  z-index: 300;
}
```

```html
<!--start header-->
<header class="box">
  <div class="header-bg"></div>
  <div class="header-gradient"></div>
  <div class="header-basis">
    <div class="header-title">
      <h1 class="sol"><i>Group</i>GMS<i>design</i></h1>
      <h1 class="dublicat"><i>Group</i>GMS<i>design</i></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!--stop header-->
<!--start menu-->
<menu>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Гостевая</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Шаблоны</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Работа с CMS</a> 
      <div class="dropdown">

      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">О нас</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</menu>
<div class="hide"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.directlyrics.com/code/lockfixed/jquery.lockfixed.min.js"></script>
```

Сам проблемный участок это "Работа с CMS" при клике на этот пункт весь контент скролится вверх,как это исправить ?\
Использовал jquery.scrollfixed.js который фиксирует блок

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/gLRdWM?editors=0010  на всякий случай ссылка на песочницу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
<li><a href="#">Работа с CMS</a>
```

на

```
<li><a href="javascript://">Работа с CMS</a>
```

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".hide").click(function() {
            $(".dropdown").hide();
            $(this).hide();
          });
          $("menu ul li:nth-child(4)").click(function() {
            $(".dropdown").show();
            $(".hide").show();
          });
        });

        (function($) {
          $.lockfixed("menu", {
            offset: {
              top: 0,
              bottom: 650,
              opacity: .4
            }
          });
        })(jQuery);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}
.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  min-height: 1800px;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
header .header-bg,
.header-gradient,
.header-basis {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.header-bg {
  background: url(http://www.tvoishuzy.com/images/new-york-city-H.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  filter: blur(5px);
  background-color: #222;
}
.header-title {
  margin: 100px;
}
menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 0, 0, .8) 60%, rgba(255, 55, 255, .7) 100%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
}
menu ul li a {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-shadow: 0 2px rgba(1, 1, 0, 1);
  color: #fefefe;
}
menu ul li div {
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 33px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 0, 0, .8) 60%, rgba(255, 55, 255, .7) 100%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 301;
}
.dublicat {
  width: 250px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  opacity: .2;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px grey;
  transition: textshadow .3s;
}
h1.sol::selection,
h1.sol i::selection {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, .4);
}
h1.dublicat::selection,
h1.dublicat i::selection {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  background: transparent!important;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px transparent;
}
.header-gradient {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red 100%, green 10%, blue 60%);
  opacity: .2;
}
.hide {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: transparent;
  display: ;
  z-index: 300;
}
```

```html
<!--start header-->
<header class="box">
  <div class="header-bg"></div>
  <div class="header-gradient"></div>
  <div class="header-basis">
    <div class="header-title">
      <h1 class="sol"><i>Group</i>GMS<i>design</i></h1>
      <h1 class="dublicat"><i>Group</i>GMS<i>design</i></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!--stop header-->
<!--start menu-->
<menu>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Гостевая</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Шаблоны</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript://">Работа с CMS</a> 
      <div class="dropdown">

      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">О нас</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</menu>
<div class="hide"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.directlyrics.com/code/lockfixed/jquery.lockfixed.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: постоянно забываю о этом ! спс